# java to find whether PostgreSQL server is running

Tags: java, postgresql

Is it possible to find whether PostgreSQL server is running or not, through java code ? I dint find any relevant solution in net. Any suggestions are really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define **running**. Is it enough for you to test whether the PostgreSQL port is available on a certain host? Is it enough to check for some `postmaster` presence on the local machine?

Comment: yes that is fine. Finding whether the post is available on the specified host.

Answer (score 3):

**Little bit funny but it will work, here username ,password and url must be correct if server is not running you will get *Failed to make connection* Check output console**

```
  try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/testdb", "username",
                    "password");

          if (connection != null) {
                System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");

        }


    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's enough for you to check for HOST+PORT availability of your PostgreSQL server, you can do:

```
public static boolean psqlAvailable(String host, int port) {
    boolean ret = false;
    try {
        Socket s = new Socket(host, port);
        ret = true;
        s.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // 
    }
    return ret;
}
```

It might be slow, though. To use it:

```
// assuming these are IP+PORT configuration on your PostgreSQL server.
boolean psql = psqlAvailable("192.168.16.1", 5432);
```